# Python - Reference Redirected Folder

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, filepath

Downloaded files location from Google Chrome is:

```
\\WALL-E\RedirectedFolders\myname\My Documents\Downloads
```

How do I reference this?

I cannot reference this in normal way like you do C: Drive.

```
path='C:\\...'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path='\\\\WALL-E\\RedirectedFolders\\rmarshall\\My Documents\\Downloads\\'
```

Comment: Why don't you use a raw string? `r'\\WALL-E\RedirectedFolders\rmarshall\My Documents\Downloads'`

Comment: You can use `r'\\WALL-E\RedirectedFolders\rmarshall\My Documents\Downloads' '\\'` if you need a trailing backslash. (string literal concatenation)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing this in windows. Assuming that what you can do is:
- Go to the Downloads folder in windows.
-Click the addressbar which will give you something like this:

```
C:\Users\TomHarris\Documents\ViberDownloads
```

Append the name of your designated file on the last of above.

```
C:\Users\TomHarris\Documents\ViberDownloads\MYFILETOOPEN
```

While I think both back-slash and forward-slash should work fine ( I am not sure though, check it!), File input in python follows convention which something like this:

```
fname= "/WALL-E/RedirectedFolders/myname/My Documents/Downloads"
```